# Whole variable including question mark and equals sign in preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match

I currently have this code:

```
$uri = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
if (preg_match("/smda/", $uri)) {
    echo "whatever;
}
```

Which catches any URL that contains "smda". I want to narrow this to any URL that contains src=smda. Am I correct in thinking that the code is this?

```
$uri = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
if (preg_match("/src=smda/", $uri)) {
    echo "whatever;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proper and the easy one is

```
if (isset($_GET['src']) && $_GET['src'] == 'smda')
{
  echo "whatever";
}
```

Comment: what if smda exists in a URL I don't want to use with this condition? e.g. http://mydomain.com/smda-page

Comment: @Alex: you did not get me, this condition will be true only if the URL contains the smda like this http://mydomain.com/somepage/?src=smda. only when `smda` is associated with `src` after the `?` mark with the equal to sign. Try it once you will get.

Comment: So I don't need to use the first line of code where I define $uri?

Comment: @Alex: you don't need that line for this purpose